# NotImplementedError: shrinkage not supported

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-discriminant

I'm running this code and I got an error witht the fit function

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(shrinkage='auto')
lda.fit(np.random.rand(3,2),np.random.randint((1,1,1)))
```

Here is the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-ec552dd1faa1> in <module>
      1 lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(shrinkage='auto')
----> 2 lda.fit(np.random.rand(3,2),np.random.randint((1,1,1)))
      3 LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py in fit(self, X, y)
    581         if self.solver == "svd":
    582             if self.shrinkage is not None:
--> 583                 raise NotImplementedError("shrinkage not supported")
    584             if self.covariance_estimator is not None:
    585                 raise ValueError(

NotImplementedError: shrinkage not supported
```

How to fix it? (got the same error upgrading scikit learn, and also on google collab)

Answer (score 1):

`shrinkage` is not supported with `svd` solver. You can use this parameter with other solvers such as `eigen` or `lsqr` as follows:

```
LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='lsqr',shrinkage='auto').fit(X_train, y_train)
```